# Question in proof of Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, probability-limit-theorems, almost-everywhere

A question came up when I was working through the proof of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem in *Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples* (pg. 76 in the fourth edition).

> **The Glivenko Cantelli Theorem:** Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables and let
>   \begin{align}
> F_{n}(x) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1(X_{i}\leq x)
> \end{align}
>   Then as $n\to \infty$ 
>   \begin{align}
> \sup_{x} | F_{n}(x) - F(x)| \to 0 \quad\text{   a.s.}
> \end{align}

The proof starts like this:

Define $Y_{i} = 1(X_{i}\leq x)$. Then we have that $\mathbb{E} Y_{i} = P(X_{i} \leq x) = F(x)$. Finally we know by the 
strong law of large numbers that
\begin{align}
F_{n}(x) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} \to F(x) \text{ a.s.}
\end{align}
FAIR ENOUGH. Can't argue with Durrett there. However, in the proof Durrett then starts talking about how we have proved that $F_{n}(x)$ converges pointwise. A quote:

> For $1\leq j\leq k-1$ let $x_{j,k} = \inf\{y : F(y)\geq j/k\}$. The
>   pointwise convergence of $F_{n}(x)$ and $F_{n}(x^{-})$ imply that we
>   can pick $N_{k}(\omega)$ so that, if $n\geq N_{k}(\omega)$, then \begin{align*} |F_{n}(x_{j,k}) -
>  F(x_{j,k})| \leq k^{-1} &&\text{ and } &&|F_{n}(x_{j,k}^{-}) -
>  F(x_{j,k}^{-})| \leq k^{-1} \end{align*}

Two questions:

1. Does $F_{n}(x)\to F(x)$ almost surely for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ imply that $F_{n}(x) \to F(x)$ pointwise for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$? Is there a proof of this?
2. If $F_{n}(x) \to F(x)$ pointwise, why is the $N_{k}(\omega)$ a function of $\omega\in\Omega$ (element of sample space) and not $x$ in the above quote?

Comment: You are right to notice that Durrett is being a bit sloppy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the details, you need to
explicitly write the $\omega$ variable. For example, the law of large
numbers guarantees that if we define
$$\Omega^\prime=\bigcap_{k\geq 2, 1\leq j<k}\left\{\omega: F_n(x_{j,k}-,\omega)\to F(x_{j,k}-)
\mbox{ and }F_n(x_{j,k},\omega)\to F(x_{j,k})\right\},$$
then $\mathbb{P}(\Omega^\prime)=1.$ For each $\omega\in\Omega^\prime$ we
have the convergence $F_n(x_{j,k}-,\omega)\to F(x_{j,k}-)$ and
$F_n(x_{j,k},\omega)\to F(x_{j,k})$, so the value $N_k(\omega)$
exists as claimed.

For  $n\geq N_k(\omega)$, Durrett's argument now gives
$\sup_x|F_n(x,\omega)-F(x)|\leq 2/k.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So when Durrett says "pointwise convergence" he is referring to the pointwise convergence $F_{n}(x,\omega) \to F(x,\omega)$ for each $x$ and each $\omega \in \Omega'$ (using your notation)?

Comment: At first, for $\omega\in\Omega^\prime$ he asserts the convergence, not at each $x$, but only at $x$ of the type $x_{j,k}$.

Comment: Of course, then he goes on to prove that $F_n(x,\omega)\to F(x,\omega)$ for all $x$, again only for $\omega\in \Omega^\prime.$